# Wifi slows down when bluetoth headset is playing sound. Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, atheros, bluetooth-speaker

WiFi slows down when Bluetooth headset is connected.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:08a6]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b571 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd    
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04ca:3015 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How can I debug/fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue too, but it's fixed in anything running Linux 4.16 or higher.
See: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/?h=v4.16.13&id=0a03f98b98c201191e3ba15a0e33f46d8660e1fd
(that's the patch)
And it's already integrated in Bionic Beaver 18.04